# Can WCF be configured to 'refactor' the XMLSchema-instance namespace on a Serialized message?

Tags: wcf, datacontractserializer

We have noted that WCF DataContractSerializer isn't very efficient when it comes to serializing `null` values during an SOAP call. For audit purposes, we also record the exact message as sent to disk, so this wastes storage. A typical message with more than one nil element is sent like so:

```
<MyMessage xmlns="myXmlns">
    <field0>1234567</field0>
    <field1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
    // etc
</MyMessage>
```

What would be an immeasurable improvement for bandwidth and disk considerations would be to generate a SOAP body such as:

```
<MyMessage xmlns="myXmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <field0>1234567</field0>
    <field1 xsi:nil="true" />
    <field2 xsi:nil="true" />
    <field3 xsi:nil="true" />
    //etc 
</MyMessage>
```

So my question is, how can I change my WCF client to consolidate the XSI namespace on the root element, to prevent it from being repeated on each nil element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tweak the serializer, however if you implement a [message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) you can manipulate to your hearts content.

If you want to drop the nulls altogether though, and never see  if it's not present you could decorate it

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
```

Comment: Thanks ... I had forgotten about `EmitDefaultValue` completely. I will give it a bash.